# How do I define a static member of a partial specialisation?

Tags: c++

As pointed out in the comments, my problem is actually:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct X {
    static int i;
};

template <typename U>
int X<int, U>::i = 42;
```

with compiler error:

```
error: template definition of non-template 'int X<int, U>::i'
7 | int X<int, U>::i = 42;
```

How can I define this static member?

Original question below.

My use case is maybe a little odd:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

template<typename ResourceType,
         typename AllocatorType>
class ResourceManager
{
public:

    typedef std::string IDType;
    typedef std::shared_ptr<ResourceType> ResourceHandle;
    typedef std::function<ResourceType(const IDType&, AllocatorType)> LoadFunc;

    static ResourceHandle GetResource(const IDType& id, AllocatorType& alloc)
    {
        auto itr = m_resources.find(id);

        if(itr != m_resources.end())
            return itr->second;

        ResourceHandle r
            = std::make_shared<ResourceType>(m_loadFunc(id, alloc));

        m_resources[id] = r;

        return r;
    }

    static std::map<IDType, ResourceHandle> m_resources;

    static LoadFunc m_loadFunc;
};

struct PretendAllocator
{

};

struct SomeResource
{
    int i;
};

template<typename Allocator>
SomeResource load_some_resouce_from_file(const std::string& filename,
                                         Allocator& alloc)
{
    SomeResource x;
    x.i = 12;
    // let's pretend that the allocator was used and the filename was used
    return x;
}

template<typename Allocator>
using SomeResourceManager = ResourceManager<SomeResource, Allocator>;

template<typename Allocator>
typename SomeResourceManager<Allocator>::LoadFunc
    SomeResourceManager<Allocator>::m_loadFunc
    = [](const SomeResourceManager<Allocator>::IDType& id,
         Allocator& alloc)
{
    return load_some_resouce_from_file(id, alloc);
}

int main()
{
    // I don't know what kind of allocator I may have in real-world
    PretendAllocator pretendAllocator;

    // But I would use it to allocate a resource managed through Manager
    SomeResourceManager<PretendAllocator>::ResourceHandle resource
        = SomeResourceManager<PretendAllocator>::GetResource("some file",
                                                             pretendAllocator);

    return 0;
}
```

This throws a bunch of compiler errors.

```
main.cpp|61|error: template definition of non-template 'typename ResourceManager<SomeResource, Allocator>::LoadFunc ResourceManager<SomeResource, Allocator>::m_loadFunc'|
main.cpp|62|error: invalid use of incomplete type 'SomeResourceManager<Allocator>'|
main.cpp|8|note: declaration of 'SomeResourceManager<Allocator>'|
main.cpp|68|error: expected ',' or '...' before 'int'|
main.cpp|77|error: expected ')' at end of input|
main.cpp|62|note: to match this '('|
main.cpp|77|error: expected '{' at end of input|
```

My use case is that I would have multiple resources which are expensive to load/acquire. So the `ResourceManager` has some code around it that will only call the static `std::function` members when absolutely required (real-world is more complex than this example).

The above seemed like the best way to do this. Basically, when defining a Resource, you would also create an alias for a `ResourceManager<YourResource>` but I now have the added complexity of needing to include an `Allocator`.

How can I get the above to compile? I'm not sure exactly what the problem is. If it's not possible, would be great to hear an alternative.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and strip off all the code irrelevant to your problem, will be much easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks @kebs to my knowledge all the code is relevant to the problem. Perhaps you could tell me what code is irrelevant so that I can ask the question more succinctly.

Comment: Indeed (except really minor stuff), apologies, I read too quickly.

Comment: Seems your "issue" can be reduced to [that](https://godbolt.org/z/sTrWbMqa4). defining static of partial specialization.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, I came to the same conclusion by changing OPs code. But I am still getting the "invalid use of incomplete type" error. Weirdly, if I define full specialization it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot partially specialise a member without partially specialising the entire class.

Insert a partial specialisation

```
template <typename U>
struct X<int, U> {
    static int i;
};
```

before the definition of `i` and it should work.